# lsof for files opened by other users

Tags: bash, lsof

How do I see the list of files open (`lsof`) in a specific directory and by other users?

I can do `lsof +D /path`, but that only shows current user's files.

Any way to see if other users have opened files in a directory?

Answer (score 5):

Since I had the similar question recently I wanted to share my findings here too. Also it is assumed that the user is `root` and as mentioned in the other answers.

List open files within a specific directory

```
lsof +D /var/log/
```

will show files opened from all users.

Specifying the user

```
lsof -u ${USER} +D /var/log/
```

will show all files from the user OR within the specific directory (... AND independet from the user).

This is because of and as stated in `man lsof`:

> Since they represent exclusions, they are applied without ORing or ANDing and take effect before any other selection criteria are applied.
>
> The -a option may be used to AND the selections.  For example, specifying -a, -U, and -ufoo produces a listing of only UNIX socket files that belong to processes owned by user ``foo''.

To list open files from the user AND within a specific directory only

```
lsof -u ${USER} -a +D /var/log/
```

It is then possible to list open files which are NOT the user AND within a specific directory.

```
lsof -u ^${USER} -a +D /var/log/
```

This approach is also working good for network connections. I.e if interested in all TCP OR UDP connections which are opened by NOT under root running processes

```
lsof -u ^root -P -i TCP -i UDP
```

To address the issue with the non root user, `sudo` and `sudoers` it will be necessary to [Identify the `sudo` calling user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522341/identify-user-in-a-bash-script-called-by-sudo).

List all open files within a specific directory AND opened from the user

```
sudo lsof -u $(who | cut -d " " -f 1) -a +D /usr/lib/
```

otherwise it would show opened files OR within the directory AND indepent from the user.

List all open files within a specific directory NOT opened by the mentioned user

```
sudo lsof -u ^$(who | cut -d " " -f 1) +D /usr/lib/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't unless you are performing this as root.

If you wanted, you can setup an `sudo` `alias` for `lsof`, but it would either be very generic.

I.e. this user can see the whole `lsof` output or very specific since this user can only see this other user's `lsof -u user` output.

Answer (score 2):

i assume you run as root / can sudo as root lsof:

```
lsof -u www-data
```

Comment: Nope, the user that's running lsof isnt (cannot be) root. However he does have rwx access to the dir and files the other user is writing to

Comment: @Ash - so user cannot. you can suid lsof or allow user to run it as root via sudo. but those are not good ideas. user needs to have access to /proc/processnumber to check current working dir for processes run by others. just read access to his home folder is not enough.