# let lsof shows longer fd length

Tags: linux, lsof

When I check a process which can use over 10000 file descriptors, lsof only shows 4 digit. (that is it can only show 9999)

When over 10000, it start with a asterisk sign. For example:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
a.out     29944 root 9995u  IPv6 846704101      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.2:50609 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root 9996u  IPv6 846706748      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.3:50634 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root 9997u  IPv6 846708259      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.4:50657 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root *000u  IPv6 846710907      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.5:50682 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root *002u  IPv6 846714817      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.6:50732 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root *003u  IPv6 846720366      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.5:50763 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root *004u  IPv6 846722078      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.6:50785 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root *005u  IPv6 846735778      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.6:50905 (ESTABLISHED)
a.out     29944 root *006u  IPv6 846736777      0t0       TCP 192.168.1.1:rtsp->192.168.1.16:50930 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

How can I get more information (more digits)?

Or what command can I use to collect all file descriptors of a process?

Answer (score 1):

Since I were running into a [somehow similar problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/87256/lsof-for-files-opened-by-other-users), I wanted to share my findings here too. I did some research regarding [Custom lsof output](https://serverfault.com/questions/514666/custom-lsof-output) and found that

> lsof's internal formatting options are quite restrictive ...

However, after reading in the manpage about **OUTPUT**, **OUTPUT FOR OTHER PROGRAMS** and in [other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163351/how-to-find-the-process-with-maximum-file-descriptors) [discussions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96632/lsof-debug-the-output-information) I've learned how to exclude certian types of file descriptors (FD), i.e.

```
lsof -u ${USER} -a -d "^mem,^cwd,^rtd,^txt"
```

or how to limit the lsof output to just numeric FDs, i.e.

```
lsof -u ${USER} -a -d "0-999999"
```

To list only numeric FDs for a specific process ID (PID) and for further processing in an other program I've used the following approach

```
lsof -p ${PID} -a -d "0-999999" -Ff
```

I haven't created and test it for bigger numbers of FDs yet, but maybe it helps collect all descriptors you are interested in.